# Hook for updating file based on package.json

Tags: git, githooks, package.json

We need to automate the process of updating our `Notice.txt` files, which is currently quite tedious.

I was reading up about git hooks, and began to thought about implementing a git hook, that does the following:

1. Look for changes in the `package.json` `dependencies` and `devDependencies`
2. Every time there is a diff in those sections, update the corresponding `Notice.txt` file.

I am unclear how to do this. Has anyone tried to tackle this in the past, or can share a guide or resource to read more about git hooks beyond the general documentation?

Answer (score 0):

From [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) you can download the Pro Git book published by Apress completely free of charge that describes git in detail. It has a `Git Hooks` section describing client and server side hooks. It also comes with some examples. Might be something worth your while checking out and hopefully help you in your problem.

Comment: Yeah, was looking on that as well, but that doesn't actually answer my question I am afraid. Managed to get up to a point, but accessing specific areas of package.json seems tricky...

Answer (score 0):

We did something similar but we did not use githooks. We were using the pre and post processes available for each npm script. For example we used the postinstall script to generate a constant accessible inside all components containing the version configured within the package.json after each install. I guess it is possible to just call a script like this in a githook.

To achieve the version constant we did the following:

**package.json**

```
"postinstall": "node version.js"
```

**version.js**

This is a file located at the same level as the package.json

```
const {version} = require('./package.json');
const {resolve, relative} = require('path');
const {writeFileSync} = require('fs-extra');

const gitInfo = {
  version: version
};

const file = resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'environments', 'version.ts');
writeFileSync(file,
  `// IMPORTANT: THIS FILE IS AUTO GENERATED! DO NOT MANUALLY EDIT OR CHECKIN!
/* tslint:disable */
export const VERSION = ${JSON.stringify(gitInfo, null, 4)};
/* tslint:enable */
`, {encoding: 'utf-8'});

console.log(`Wrote version info ${gitInfo.version} to ${relative(resolve(__dirname, '..'), file)}`);
```

**result: version.ts under /environment**

The code above generated a version.ts file into the environment folder with the following content

```
// IMPORTANT: THIS FILE IS AUTO GENERATED! DO NOT MANUALLY EDIT OR CHECKIN
/* tslint:disable */
export const VERSION = {
  'version': 'VERSION FROM PACKAGE.JSON'
};
/* tslint:enable */
```